# Electron app doesn't print when using silence:true in linux

Tags: angular, electron

I created an app following all the guidelines of creating electron app according the the framework's API, but using silence:false , prints well after choosing the default printer in linux.
But using the silence: false doesn't print.

Answer (score 0):

It should be "silent" (not silence).

```
win.webContents.print({
    silent:false
});
```